# Preflight request is sent with all methods

Tags: javascript, angular, cors, preflight

My FE application is using API from different domain. I know that it should trigger CORS, but as I understood it shouldn't create preflight for every request.

According to [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS), I shouldn't have preflight request for `GET` method.

```
 Cross-site requests are preflighted like this since they may have implications to 
 user data. In particular, a request is preflighted if:

    - It uses methods other than GET, HEAD or POST. 
Also, if POST is used to send request data with a Content-Type 
other than application/x-www-form-urlencoded, multipart/form-data, 
or text/plain, e.g. if the POST request sends an XML payload to the
server using application/xml or text/xml, then the request is preflighted.
    - It sets custom headers in the request 
(e.g. the request uses a header such as X-PINGOTHER)
```

However, every request that I'm sending, has preflight (OPTIONS) request, no matter if it's GET or POST, and I find it strange (according to what docs said).

I set some headers (and I'm sending it with `withCredentials: true`), but I don't see that it should be the issue:

```
  headers.append('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', FRONTEND_URL);
  headers.append('Accept', 'application/json');
  headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
  headers.append('Authorization', this._generateApiKey());
  headers.append('Language', this._languageISOCode);
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: WithCredentials is your custom header, which means it gets preflighted for GET/POST requests

Answer (score 41, accepted):

See https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Simple_requests

A CORS preflight `OPTIONS` request can be triggered just by adding a `Content-Type` header to a request — if the value’s anything except `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, `text/plain`, or `multipart/form-data`. And that’s true even for `GET` requests (though you should never add a `Content-Type` header to a `GET` — because there’s no request body, so it serves no purpose).

And among the headers shown in the question, the `Authorization` header will also trigger a preflight, as will the "`Language`" header (which isn’t even a standard header name; maybe `Accept-Language` was intended?), and the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header (which isn’t even a request header; it’s a response header that should never be used in frontend code).

As far as the headers that *don’t* trigger a preflight: the Fetch spec (which defines CORS behavior) specifies what it calls a [**CORS-safelisted request-header**](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#cors-safelisted-request-header), and defines as one of:

- `Accept`
- `Accept-Language`
- `Content-Language`
- `Content-Type` whose value, once parsed, has a MIME type (ignoring parameters) that is `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, `multipart/form-data`, or `text/plain`

Any request — including any `GET` request — which contains a header that’s not among those  **CORS-safelisted request-headers** listed above will trigger a preflight.

---

To help make all that more clear, I updated [the MDN docs about CORS “simple requests”](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Simple_requests) and [the MDN docs about CORS preflighted requests](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Preflighted_requests) (it’s slightly more complicated than what’s described above, actually—but what’s above suffices for the context of this question).

---

Note that WebKit/Safari places additional restrictions on the values allowed in the `Accept`, `Accept-Language`, and `Content-Language` headers.

If any of those headers have ”non-standard” values, WebKit/Safari will do a preflight.

As far as what WebKit/Safari considers “non-standard” values for those headers, that’s not really documented except in the following WebKit bugs:

- [Require preflight for non-standard CORS-safelisted request headers Accept, Accept-Language, and Content-Language](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=165178)
- [Allow commas in Accept, Accept-Language, and Content-Language request headers for simple CORS](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=165566)
- [Switch to a blacklist model for restricted Accept headers in simple CORS requests](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=166363)

No other browsers impose those extra restrictions, because they’re not part of the spec. They were unilaterally added to WebKit with no  discussion with the spec editor or other browsers.

Comment: _that’s not a CORS-safelisted request-header_ - do you mean that is not in the list of 4 headers you showed?

Comment: Yes, any header that is not in the list of of 4 headers above.

Answer (score 0):

The cross-domain issue typically occurs when the application is hosted on one domain, the web service is hosted on a different domain and we are trying to make an Ajax call to get the response.
An Ajax call to our web services ended with a CORS error.The HTTP method that was invoked was OPTIONS and not GET or POST.

Resolving this issue was one aspect but we still needed to retain the security authentication. Otherwise, we would end up exposing an unauthenticated web service which is a threat.

```
if (request.getMethod().equals("OPTIONS") && request.getHeader(ORIGIN).equals(FRONTEND_URL))
{
response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", FRONTEND_URL);
response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, HEAD");
response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers",request.getHeader("Access-Control-Request-Headers"));
}
```